# Skip hidden rows

Tags: vba

I have made a userform where I have made a button and when I press it it should take the next one on the list in a table. If I then filter the list, I would like it to skip the hidden rows. What should I add?

Thanks in advance.

````
Dim answer As Integer

answer = MsgBox("Har du husket at opdatere oplysninger?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Opdatere oplysninger")

If answer = vbYes Then

Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Sheets("Haller").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If currentRow = lastrow Then
        MsgBox "Du er nu ved den sidste på listen", vbCritical
    Else
        txt1dato.Text = ""
        cboResultat.Text = ""
        txtGenkald.Text = ""
        txtDatoMøde.Text = ""
        cboBetjener.Text = ""
        txtMailBetjener.Text = ""
        txtVNavn.Text = ""
        txtVAdresse.Text = ""
        txtVPostnr.Text = ""
   
        
        currentRow = currentRow + 1
        
        txt1dato.Text = Cells(currentRow, 7)
        cboResultat.Text = Cells(currentRow, 2)
        txtGenkald.Text = Cells(currentRow, 3)
        txtDatoMøde.Text = Cells(currentRow, 4)
        cboBetjener.Text = Cells(currentRow, 5)
        txtMailBetjener.Text = Cells(currentRow, 6)
        txtVNavn.Text = Cells(currentRow, 1)
        txtVAdresse.Text = Cells(currentRow, 8)
        txtVPostnr.Text = Cells(currentRow, 9)
 
End If```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to check for hidden rows?
Like:

```
Dim answer As Integer

answer = MsgBox("Har du husket at opdatere oplysninger?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Opdatere oplysninger")

If answer = vbYes Then

    Dim lastrow As Long

    lastrow = Sheets("Haller").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If currentRow = lastrow Then
        MsgBox "Du er nu ved den sidste på listen", vbCritical

    Else
        do
            currentRow = currentRow  + 1
        loop until ((Sheets("Haller").Rows(currentRow).Hidden = false) or (currentRow = lastrow))

        if (currentRow < lastrow ) then
            txt1dato.Text = ""
            cboResultat.Text = ""
            txtGenkald.Text = ""
            txtDatoMøde.Text = ""
            cboBetjener.Text = ""
            txtMailBetjener.Text = ""
            txtVNavn.Text = ""
            txtVAdresse.Text = ""
            txtVPostnr.Text = ""
 
    
            txt1dato.Text = Cells(currentRow, 7)
            cboResultat.Text = Cells(currentRow, 2)
            txtGenkald.Text = Cells(currentRow, 3)
            txtDatoMøde.Text = Cells(currentRow, 4)
            cboBetjener.Text = Cells(currentRow, 5)
            txtMailBetjener.Text = Cells(currentRow, 6)
            txtVNavn.Text = Cells(currentRow, 1)
            txtVAdresse.Text = Cells(currentRow, 8)
            txtVPostnr.Text = Cells(currentRow, 9)
        Else
            msgbox "nothing to show"
        End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using Range.SpecialCells Method (xlCellTypeVisible) all visible cells?

It works only with visible cells in range.